# C# Serilog only receive an e-mail after an error

Tags: c#, email, serilog, sink

I am using Serilog Sink *Serilog.Sinks.Email*.
I get the email. Unfortunately also with the "information". 
I would like to receive emails first if it is a warning error or fatal.

Is there a way to set this? The "information" should no longer be sent in the e-mail. **BUT** the information should be re-written into the .txt file.
I would like to receive emails if it is a warning, error or fatal.

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .WriteTo.RollingFile("logs\\log.txt")
                            .WriteTo.Email(
                            fromEmail: "LOG",
                            toEmail: "ghost-user@ghost.com",
                            mailServer: "exchange")
                            .CreateLogger();

    Log.Information("++ I'm starting logging ++");
    Log.Error("Only that should arrive in the e-mail");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`restrictedToMinimumLevel` will do this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.RollingFile("logs\\log.txt")
    .WriteTo.Email(
        restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Warning,
        fromEmail: "LOG",
        toEmail: "ghost-user@ghost.com",
        mailServer: "exchange")
    .CreateLogger();
```